# NullPointerException when deploying the MBO

Tags: java, sup

I am deploying the MBOs in SUP 2.2 and it is failing with the Null Pointer Exception.

```
Errors occurred while creating packages. 
Deployment Error: Create package failed (package=/TestforSR/.pkg, server=MOF Server) 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But it is working fine and able to fetch the response when preview and by using the SOAPUI utilities and not throwing any error or exception. Only the exception when deploying the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around for the issue. Not sure if this is the only solution but this is working for me and MBOs are getting deployed to the SUP Server successfully without throwing the Null Pointer Exception.

The webservice that i was using had some parameters of datatype set as enum, which is not supported by SUP and by changing the parameter datatype from enum to String resolved the issue, and error is no more there.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are connected the SUP server? And while deploying, it would be better to use the

> Update

mode.

Comment: SUP Server is connected. I am able to ping the SUP Server as well. Already tried the 'Update' 'Replace' mode for deploying the package, but still failing.